# Fixing Emacs' hl-line mode for the last line of a buffer

Tags: emacs

When I enable hl-line-mode, the last line of the file is only highlighted until its last character (and not at all if the line is empty) instead of all the way through like the other lines.  A dirty fix is to add an empty line at the end of the file, but I was wondering if there was a better way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that's the correct fix.  What you're seeing is that the line and file ends  where the highlighting ends.  If there were a newline at the end, then the whole line would highlight.

Change the setting in emacs that guarantees a file ends with newline with

```lisp
(setq require-final-newline t)
```

or through customize and not only will you find the visual appearance you like, you'll find a surprising number of other tools (eg make(1)) behave better.

Comment: I have that setting, but sometimes I just open a new buffer to jot down some notes.  I was hoping it was a setting (or bug that possibly another line highlighting mode fixes).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change hl-line-mode to also highlight the end of buffer as if it were a LF, you could that by adding a overlay with an after-string.